# What is the logic behind cocomac's answer?

Tags: discussion

This post contains a euphemism.

Unfortunately, the gentlemen that made the rules made it so you need reputation to comment and ask not to edit an answer to reply to the author, so I have to ask a separate question.

I tried to find if you can run Minecraft: Bedrock Edition betas in GNU and found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1379067/is-there-any-way-i-can-play-minecraft-bedrock-edition-for-free-in-ubuntu).

The accepted answer was:

> Tl;dr: No, you can't.
>
> Here's the real answer:
>
> You have two issues:
>
> 1. Minecraft Java Edition [can be downloaded for Linux](https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/download). After you pay for the game, of course. Minecraft Bedrock Edition (a.k.a. Minecraft: Windows 10 Edition) won't work on Ubuntu (or any other Linux distro, for that matter). It is distributed via [the Microsoft/Xbox store](https://www.xbox.com/en-us/games/store/Minecraft-for-Windows/9NBLGGH2JHXJ). Not a downloadable `.exe`. So you can't download that version for Ubuntu. [Some people](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/qemtk8/i_got_minecraft_bedrock_running_with_wine_dxvk_on/) (Reddit link) have gotten it working on Linux. [Here](https://mcpelauncher.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) is another one. So it is technically possible, just hard.
> 2. It isn't free. Neither Minecraft: Java Edition nor Minecraft: Bedrock Edition are free (on Windows, Mac, or Linux). So you have to pay.
>
> If you want an easy way, I'd just create a Windows 10 VM using [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/), or just play Minecraft: Java Edition.

I don't understand this answer. What do you have to pay for? Neither Bedrock release nor Bedrock betas are free, and I don't think any of them is distributed as .exe, but release is paid, and betas are foc. Does that mean that you have to pay more for release?

Comment: @Rinzwind It says page not found

Comment: This is the link: [help], and also [tour].

Comment: @Orisphera sorry needs a space before "as" :) Removed it as Artur did a better job than me ;=)

Comment: "Unfortunately, the gentlemen that made the rules made it so you need reputation to comment and ask not to edit an answer to reply to the author, so I have to ask a separate question."  that is to protect the site from bots and ppl that want to post random crap on websites and the likes. It took me mere SECONDS to get the reputation to post comments when I started and if I could do that so can you ;-)

Comment: @Rinzwind I guess I'm not as good at this as you are. Can you please post my question as a comment to that answer?

Comment: > What do you have to pay for? < Minecraft is not free software.  You have to pay for a Minecraft account.  Java Edition for Linux can be downloaded, but you still have to login to the launcher to use it.  This is the way since Minecraft was purchased by Microsoft.  HOWEVER, your question here reads more like a question that should be on the main site, NOT here on Meta because it's not about the site itiself.

Answer (score 5):

(I'm cocomac - the user that posted that)

Regarding the requirement to have more reputation to comment, see the post on MSE (the discussion site for the Stack Exchange network of sites) called [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

I'm somewhat confused by exactly what you're asking, but I'll do my best to clarify.

Regarding the rest of your question, I mean the game costs money for the game. I.e., it isn't free. That's what costs money - the game.

I'm not sure that you're statement of "the betas are foc" is correct. As far as I'm aware, beta/preview versions of Minecraft aren't free and require you to own the game.

If I misunderstood and you you mean the Demo version of the game, I'm not sure if you can run that on Ubuntu (that would be a separate question, though).

Comment: +1 for providing a good answer. I have posted so many answers on Ask Ubuntu that it is difficult for me to keep them all up to date. My preferred way of handling user feedback on one of my answers is via the comments, but in this case the user does not have sufficient reputation (only 1) to comment.

Answer (score 4):

Seems like a simple misunderstanding.

Microsoft (Mojang) charges for player accounts that use the client launcher (including single-player mode).

However, multiplayer servers --like the Minecraft Java Server-- are distributed and licensed for use free of charge.

Client = Proprietary/Paid.
Server = Proprietary/Free-of-charge.

In this case, A assumes you are treating both Client and Server as a single system (paid), while B assumes server alone (free).

A + B = misunderstanding.